# Script error: ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python

I want the below python-script to send the data when executed to my InfluxDB.

But when I execute the script I get an error saying "ValueError: too many values to unpack". What am I doing wrong?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

import time

#foo = kamstrup()
foo = kamstrup(serial_port="/dev/ttyAMA0", baud_rate=1200)

for i in kamstrup_MC601_var:
    x,u = foo.readvar(i)
    print("%-25s" % kamstrup_MC601_var[i], x, u)

    import requests
    url_string = 'http://192.168.0.11:8086/write?db=test_kamstrup'
    data_string = 'kamstrup_script,host=server01,region=us-west value={' + kamstrup_MC601_var[i], x, u + '}'

    r = requests.post(url_string, data=data_string)
```

Comment: please post the full traceback. also, it looks like you intend `data_string` to be a string, when it is in fact a tuple. this could be the problem

Comment: If the error happens in the for loop, it's possible that `kamstrup_MC601_var` is not an iterable of a single object, like a list of ints `[0, 1, 2, ...], but an iterable containing multiple values per iteration, e.g. `[(0, 1), (0, 2), ...]` This is just an assumption please post more details

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: And when you are happy with the answer you got, then please accept it, instead of asking *another* question within comments. Seriously: you are doing many many thing wrong that are nicely explained in the [help]. You want others to spend their free time to help you, so you please spend the time required to learn how this community works!

Answer (score 0):

The error probably rises from here;

```
x,u = foo.readvar(i)
```

you have provided not enough assigner to assign data

For example:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> x,y = a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

You can solve this with either providing exact number of variables for the assignment or use this:

```
x, *u = foo.readvar(i)
```

this will get the first one and assign to `x` and the rest will be assigned to `u` as a list.